# Prove implication sequent

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I need to prove the sequent $P \to Q \vdash \neg P \lor Q$ without using the law of the excluded middle $(P \lor \neg P)$ or $( Q \lor \neg Q)$.

Comment: What can you use instead? If the law of excluded middled is false then $(p\to q)\to(\neg p\vee q)$  is false.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the other way round? The sequent $P \to Q \vdash \neg P \vee Q$ implies the law of exluded middle, since $P \to P$ is provable almost immediately and so $P \vee \neg P$ follows. However, you can prove $\neg P \vee Q \vdash P \to Q$ without the law of excluded middle.

Comment: @ajotatxe The OP probably means the syntactic rule of LEM cannot be used, but other rules (that implicitly rely on LEM, such as RAA) can.

Comment: @ajotatxe just the rule of LEM is forbidden.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a proof done in Fitch:

[image]